# retrieve top 100 and then search in all records

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

I have window -with dw object- when i open this window i retrieve all records in the datawindow (`dw_1.retrieve()`)

When user wants to search for a specific record i put criteria he enters in valid expression (`ls_filter`)

then

```
dw_1.setfilter(ls_filter)
dw_1.filter()
```

My app works fine when server is on local network.

Now it is required to put server on the net(cloud) so in open event i can not retrieve all rows as it take about five minutes to retrieve all rows(very very long period).

So in sql synatx of `dw_1` I added `top 100` (after select) that make dw to retrieve only last 100 rows

My question is: if user want to search for specific record, is this mean i must retrieve all rows to search and thus take long time again to load all rows ?

Is this right? Or is there another solution? How?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use filters. Instead you need to add retrieval argument in sql query using `where` clause. Now whenever you need to search the particular record, just use

Add retrieval argument from menu `design` -> `retrieval arguments`

Lets say you added retrieval argument filter `varchar (100)`

Your query should be :

```
Select top 100 * from tablename where (:filter is null and 1=1)
```

Or

```
(columnxyz like :filter)
```

On `open()` of window pass `null` string while retrieving.

```
String is_filter;  // instance variable
Setnull(is_filter);
Dw_1.retrieve (is_filter)
```

On retrieving filtered content only :

```
is_filter=sle_control.text;
Dw_1.retrieve (is_filter)
```

You can also visit this blog :

http://bishtpowerbuilder.blogspot.in/2016/10/4-datawindows-strength-of-powerbuilder_25.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing is to apply a where in the dw and not use the filter. Less records less time.